# Validate the field so that it does not accept spaces and special characters

Tags: jquery

I have a field for a form where the user cannot put spaces and special characters. How can I do this validation with Jquery?

```
<label for="ref">Reference</label>
<input class="btn btn-primary" id="ref" name="Reference">
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it as follows:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="name" spellcheck="false" data-ms-editor="true"> <button type="submit">Testar</button>
</form>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$('#name').on('keypress', function() {
var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9-Zàèìòùáéíóúâêîôûãõ\b]+$");
var _this = this;
setTimeout( function(){
    var texto = $(_this).val();
    if(!regex.test(texto))
    {
        $(_this).val(texto.substring(0, (texto.length-1)))
    }
}, 100);
});
</script>
```